# Cocoa touch save playlist

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audio-player

In cocoa touch 4.x Its possible create or edit a music playlist into the default/bundle music app for iphone/ipad? if it is, how will be the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access information from the iPod Library ([iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765)) by creating `MPMediaQuery`s. This will allow you to retrieve playlists (using the `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate`) but I don't think you'll be able to create playlists as you are only given read-only access (as well as playback).

Comment: But Shazam app creates its own playlist named "My Shazam Tracks". How did they do that?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the solution for iOS 9.3 and above. You can use MPMediaLibrary to achieve that.

```
// Setup your playlist metadata
__auto_type metadata = [[MPMediaPlaylistCreationMetadata alloc] initWithName:@"Playlist Name"];
metadata.authorDisplayName = @"My app name";
metadata.descriptionText = @"Playlist description";

// Save it to get the same playlist next time
NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID UUID];

// Items to add to your playlist
NSArray<MPMediaItem *> *mediaItems = self.items;

// Get or create your playlist in Apple Music
[[MPMediaLibrary defaultMediaLibrary] getPlaylistWithUUID:uuid creationMetadata:metadata completionHandler:^(MPMediaPlaylist * _Nullable playlist, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    // Handle the error
    NSLog(@"Got error — %@", error);

    // You can add items to your playlist
    [playlist addMediaItems:mediaItems completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable addError) {
        // Handle the error
        NSLog(@"finished! error — %@", addError);
    }];
}];
```